# Prolog: last element and the rest of a list

Tags: prolog

Is there a way to separate a list in Prolog like this: `[1,2,3,4|5]`?
I can write a predicate which separates a head from a tail:
`predicate([Head|Tail]).`
And I would like to know if I can write something like this:
`predicate([Init|Last]).` Init and Last are used in Haskell to separate the last element from its list. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The keyword you need to search for is `Difference List`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`last/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=last/2) to yield the last element of a list.

```
?- A = [1,2,3,4,5], last(A, B). 
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
B = 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

`[1,2,3,4|5]` is not a proper list, the tail should be a list itself (recursive definition). But you could use append/3 from library(lists) to perform a call that yields the front elements and the last one, like in `?- L=[1,2,3,4,5],append(Xs,[Last],L).`.